# How to make the same button swap text each time it is clicked?

Tags: javascript

If I have a paragraph

```
<p id=peed></p>
```

and I have a button which on click runs this function:

```
<script>
  var x = 'welcome'
  function onButtonClick() {
    document.getElementById('peep').innerHTML = [x];
  }
</script>
```

This swaps the peep paragraph with variable `x`.

How, using if statements, would I make the same button when clicked a second time reverse this an replace `x` with the paragraph peep again?

Comment: check for document.getElementById("peep").innerHTML text and make your condition accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Function like that?

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
     var tmp = document.getElementById("peep").innerHTML;
     if(tmp === 'x') {
        document.getElementById("peep").innerHTML = 'y';
     }
     else {
        document.getElementById("peep").innerHTML = 'x';
     }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

With ES6, you could use the [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for swapping the variable and the actual text.

```js
var a = 5, b = 2;
  
[a, b] = [b, a];
 
console.log(a, b); // 2 5
```

Implementation

```js
var x = 'welcome';

function peep() {
    [document.getElementById("peep").innerHTML, x] = [x, document.getElementById("peep").innerHTML];
}
```

```html
<button onclick="peep()">peep</button>
<div id="peep">some text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to get the original content:

```
var originalPeep = document.getElementById("peep").innerHTML;
```

You need to have a variable to store whether it has been replaced or not:

```
var replaced = false;
```

Now in your function, you need to check the value of `replaced` and replace it accordingly (and reset our `replaced` marker):

```
function myFunction() {
    if (replaced) {
        document.getElementById("peep").innerHTML = originalPeep;
        replaced = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("peep").innerHTML = x;
        replaced = true;
    }
}
```

So in total that becomes:

```
var originalPeep = document.getElementById("peep").innerHTML;
var replaced = false;

function myFunction() {
    if (replaced) {
        document.getElementById("peep").innerHTML = originalPeep;
        replaced = false;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("peep").innerHTML = x;
        replaced = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Good explanation

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = 'welcome'
var peeepText = '';
function myFunction() {
  if (!peeepText) {
    peeepText = document.getElementById("peep").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById('peep').innerHTML = [x];
  } else {
    document.getElementById('peep').innerHTML = peepText;
    peepText = '';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing this with an array an count as well.

```
var x = [];
x[0] = 'welcome';
x[1] = 'googbye';
var count = 1;
function myFunction()
{
  document.getElementById('peep').innerHTML = x[count%2];
  count++;
}
```

Comment: This is a pretty convoluted way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Swapping values is tricky: you need to store the current value in a temporary variable, replace the current value with the new one, then assign the temporary value to the variable holding new one.

```js
document.querySelector("button").onclick = myFunction;

var x = 'welcome';

function myFunction()
{
    var peep = document.getElementById("peep");
    var tmp = peep.innerHTML;
    peep.innerHTML = x;
    x = tmp;
}
```

```html
<div id="peep">peep</div>
<button>swap</button>
```

Comment: Cheers, this is the best and most simple one, works perfectly.